# "Unprintable IUnknown*" found in IDL of Interop Type Library

Tags: c#, vb.net, com, idl

I am defining a series COM-callable interfaces that I can use to access a .NET assembly from VBA, a setup similar to what I have done many times in the past.  For this set of classes, in cases where the managed code uses optional nullable parameters on a method, I have defined on the interface a method that uses variants.  This code seems to function correctly in that when calling from VBA, I can pass either of the parameters as empty or filled values and the .NET receives the optional parameters correctly, as either nulls or as an object that I can try to cast and use.  The odd thing is that when reading the IDL for type library I created using REGASM I see:

```
HRESULT SetCommentData(
   [in, optional, defaultvalue(<unprintable IUnknown*>)] VARIANT sequencenumber, 
   [in, optional, defaultvalue("")] BSTR Message);
```

The method definitions in .NET are:

VB.NET:

```
'managed definition in class
Public Sub SetCommentData(Optional sequencenumber As Decimal? = Nothing, _
                 Optional message As String = Nothing)


'managed definition in class for COM
Public Sub SetCommentData(Optional sequencenumber As Object = Nothing, _
                     Optional message As String = Nothing) Implements _
                     _RoutingComment.SetCommentData


'managed definition in interface
Sub SetCommentData(Optional sequencenumber As Object = Nothing, _
                     Optional message As String = Nothing)
```

or if you prefer in C#:

```
//managed definition in class
public void SetCommentData(decimal? sequencenumber = null, string message = null)

//managed definition in class for COM
public void SetCommentData(object sequencenumber = null, string message = null)

//managed definition in interface
void SetCommentData(object sequencenumber = null, string message = null)
```

My guess is that COM does not know what a .NET null object is and that is why it defaults to IUnknown.  The setting the string default to "" is kind of interesting (especially since I said null!), but I imagine that must have been a special case in REGASM.  I kind of think that it does not matter to the caller what the default value ever is, so it is provided more as Intellisense information for the programmer than for the binder/compiler.  Since it is working, maybe I should not worry about this IDL, but I would like to know if is there a COMAttribute or something that I could apply to clarify that the default is null.  The VBA object viewer does not seem to pay any attention to default values, displaying:

```
Sub SetCommentData([sequencenumber], [Message As String])
```

In short, is this a negligible interop artifact that is informational only, or could this, in some context, have an meaningful effect on a program?  Have no idea what unprintable means in this context, so anyone who knows that could chime in about that too.

Comment: [MIDL docs for default value, not especially helpful](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366793%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: COM does not know anything about Decimal?, the `Nullable<T>` type is a pure .NET type that does not have an equivalent in other languages.  So the feature will never be used and if you try to use it anyway then whatever compiler reads the type library is going to spit bullets.  If you want to provide a default value feature then you'll have to use Object instead.  Maps to a VARIANT on the VBA side.  I think you'll get Type.Missing, maybe Nothing, you'll have to try.

Comment: @HansPassant  I realize that a nullable is only going to work in .NET.  That is why I intentionally changed the original .NET decimal? signature to a signature with object, for exposure to COM.  This did map to a Variant as my IDL shows, and it did work correctly. A missing in COM became a null in .NET, a currency in COM, became a decimal in .NET.